# Zxing Barcode Scanning (Fixed Distance Focus)

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

Afternoon All Experts,

I have a barcode scanning Android program that will start scanning after a button is press. The camera will start to auto focus and capture the barcode and return the value. This work fine.

But when user press the button again for the next barcode, it will start to auto focus again. It had no problem in scanning the next Barcode and return the value.

I am wondering if it is possible to fixed the camera focus distance so that it is control by the user to move the device to a certain predefine distance to focus on the Barcode for scanning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any one having any idea for this?